# Best way to show nullable boolean actionable or actionless state

Tags: gui-design

Please note that I have seen these questions:

[Boolean table cell values - best way to show Yes/No](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/31470/boolean-table-cell-values-best-way-to-show-yes-no)
[What is the best way to display nullable bool value as UI component?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/87122/what-is-the-best-way-to-display-nullable-bool-value-as-ui-component)

My situation is different. I want to show these things all together:

- Flat inheritance and overriding (not hierarchical, not a tree)
- For parent levels, I only want to show nullable boolean values
- For the current level, I want to show the current nullable boolean value **AND** I want to provide actions to change it
- I want to show the overall state (the overriding tree's result)
- And I want to show these states + actions in a compact way inside a list

This is my current design, which is very poor.

[image]

Now let me explain the requirements. We have a SPL (software production line). We want to allow configuration to be granular (both gross and fine). We want our customers to be able to:

- Configure commenting to be disabled for the entire system
- And be able to enable commenting for the blog module (a subsystem, module-level)
- And be able to disable it for authors (a subsystem of the blog, entity-type level)
- And be able to disable it for a special category of blog posts (a subsystem of taxonomy, entity level, cross-module functionality)
- And be able to enable it again for a specific blog post (entity level)

So, when a customer goes to configure the post titled `Is it a good idea to buy bitcoin`, we want to show him that:

- Commenting is disabled in the entire system
- For module blog, it's not configured (null)
- For all blog posts, it's enabled
- For this specific post, it's not configured yet

What is the best way to satisfy those requirements?